# Link alt appears in separate div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to jQuery, so I would appreciate any help/advice you can offer!

What i am trying to do:
Basically, I just need the alt of the link to replace the description text (located in separate div) of the parent div when you hover over the link. I had gotten this to work for a single row but when I have multiple columns with multiple rows I am having an issue. I cannot seem to get the script to grab the parent element description, nor replace it with the alt from the hovered text.
[jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/LUAtb/26/)

Please maybe explain what it is I'm doing wrong.

[image]

My HTML:

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  $("#description").text(id.desc);
  $("a.description").hover(
    function() {
      $("#description").text($(this).attr("desc"));
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="1" desc="Div Description for div 1" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3>Link set 1-1</h3>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link1-1" desc="Sample Alt Text 1-1" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link1-2" desc="Sample Alt Text 1-2" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link1-3" desc="Sample Alt Text 1-3" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link1-4" desc="Sample Alt Text 1-4" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3>Link set 1-2</h3>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link1-51" desc="Sample Alt Text 1-5" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link1-6" desc="Sample Alt Text 1-6" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link1-7" desc="Sample Alt Text 1-7" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link1-8" desc="Sample Alt Text 1-8" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div id="description"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="2" desc="Div Description for div 2" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3>Link set 2-1</h3>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link2-1" desc="Sample Alt Text 2-1" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link2-2" desc="Sample Alt Text 2-2" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link2-3" desc="Sample Alt Text 2-3" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link2-4" desc="Sample Alt Text 2-4" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3>Link set 2-2</h3>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link2-5" desc="Sample Alt Text 2-5" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link2-6" desc="Sample Alt Text 2-6" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link2-7" desc="Sample Alt Text 2-7" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="link2-8" desc="Sample Alt Text 2-8" href="/">Link </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div id="description"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it's a tool tip, use title="" rather than alt, which is meant for images, rather than an a tag. Also, i don't see any a tags with a class description. I can't dig into this right now but i'm not really clear on what you are trying to achieve. Is there a working demo that is close to what you need?

Comment: id like to use the desc rather than alt and not have the tooltip for seo reasons. just forgot to change the alt to desc will replace now.

Comment: @RichBailo use the valid `data-*` attribute instead (`data-alt="blah"` in your specific case)

Comment: But for SEO, the link copy will get indexed, so what's between the a tags. Webcraws have a hard time processing DOM changes for indexing.

Comment: @RichBailo since when "desc" is a valid HTML attribute?

Comment: I understand your concerns with the html code and will address the HTML, I am really trying to get the script to work per parent element with elements under. trying to focus on the element parent of the element that is hovered over.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan do you maybe have an example that would help me.

Comment: your #description is in the document twice. Also $("#description").text(id.desc); gives an error because id is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/sosigi/edit?html,css,js,output

1. You cannot use **duplicate** ID `id=description` inside your document.
2. `a.description` and **you don't have any** `<a class="description"` at all.
3. `alt` is an **invalid** `A` element attribute and `desc` is unknown to HTML's attributes list.

Use the valid `data-*` attribute **and the right selectors**

```js
jQuery(function( $ ) {
  
  $("[data-desc]").hover(function(e) {
    var mEnter = e.type==="mouseenter";
    var $descTerget = $(this).closest(".row").find(".description");
    $descTerget.text( mEnter ? $(this).data("desc") : "");
  });
  
});
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="div1"class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h3>Link set 1-1</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link1-1" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 1-1" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link1-2" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 1-2" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link1-3" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 1-3" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link1-4" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 1-4" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h3>Link set 1-2</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link1-5" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 1-5" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link1-6" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 1-6" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link1-7" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 1-7" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link1-8" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 1-8" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="description"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="div2" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h3>Link set 2-1</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link2-1" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 2-1" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link2-2" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 2-2" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link2-3" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 2-3" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link2-4" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 2-4" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h3>Link set 2-2</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link2-5" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 2-5" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link2-6" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 2-6" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link2-7" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 2-7" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="link2-8" data-desc="Sample Alt Text 2-8" href="/">Link </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="description"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```